# Error uploading base64 image to Cloudinary

Tags: php, base64, cloudinary

When I try to upload their sample base64 (it has 85bytes) :

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==")
```

Everything is fine, but when I try to upload some of mine images it says:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Cloudinary\Error' with message 'Error in sending request to server - couldn't open file "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlz AAAN1wAADdcBQiibeAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAAAPCSURB VGiB7ZlLaFxlGIaf72SMNQloQemcGQRvaJGW1GQiCN4mmzhn4lKEJk0V3'....

Comment: Your source code doesn't look like PHP code, what language is this in?

Comment: Looks like Ruby to me...

Comment: for php is :
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("data:image/png;base64,".$base64_string);

I copied from documentation, that was for ruby, sorry...

Comment: It was really stupid mistake, I don't know if I can say that was even a typo.
I was testing with some random base64 String that I generated online and copied to .php script and that String was bigger than one row, so that caused all the problems that I had and it was some type of bug... 
Thank you for your time and will to help :)